# How to setup multi instances using percona xtradb cluster?

Tags: mysql, percona, xtradb, galera

we are using 3node percona-xtradb cluster.
Now we are planning to add one more instance in all 3 nodes and make it as a another cluster group.
How to setup multi instances using percona xtradb cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if we talk about the same when you mention multi-intance set-ups...

Multi-intance set-ups in my understanding is running several mysqld processes on the same machine.

According to this definition it is possibly to have several Galera nodes on one machine (belonging to the same cluster or not does not mater). The trick is to not conflict IP addresses and ports.

If it makes sense is an other question...

We do it a as follows:

```
# Node 1 of 2nd Cluster
[mysqld]
port                  = 3307
socket                = /tmp/mysql-3307.sock
wsrep_cluster_address = "gcomm://192.168.1.2:5677,192.168.1.3:5677?gmcast.listen_addr=tcp://192.168.1.1:5677"
```

To make it easier to operate we use MyEnv (MySQL multi-instance set-up environment): http://www.fromdual.com/myenv-mysql-basenv

Regards,
Oli